# How to strip letters out of a string and compare values?

Tags: python, excel

I have just learned Python for this project I am working on and I am having trouble comparing two values - I am using the Python xlwt and xlrd libraries and pulling values of cells from the documents. The problem is some of the values are in the format 'NP_000000000', 'IPI00000000.0', and '000000000' so I need to check which format the value is in and then strip the characters and decimal points off if necessary before comparing them.

I have tried using `S1[:3]` to get the value without alphabet characters, but I get a 'float is not subscriptable' error

Then I tried doing `re.sub(r'[^\d.]+, '', S1)` but I get a Typerror: expected a string or buffer

I figured since the value of the cell that is being returned via `sheet.cell( x, y).value` would be a string since it is alphanumeric, but it seems like it must be returned as a float

What is the best way to format these values and then compare them?

Comment: Can you post the result you get for `repr(S1)`, please?

Comment: `S1` is a float, not a string ... so apparently you're not getting a homogeneous type from whatever is pulling the cells from the documents.

Comment: from repr(S1) I get `u'IPI00227299.4'`  I am not super familiar with Python, but is this the unicode foramt?

Comment: @FreshPeter: Yes, that's a Unicode string, and `S1[3:]` should work perfectly fine on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the numbers from the strings in the format shown? Like to get 2344 from NP_2344? If yes then use this

```
float(str(S1)[3:])
```

to get what you want. You can change float to int.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the API you're using is returning different types depending on the content of the cells. You have two options.

1. You can convert everything to a string and then do what you're currently doing:

   s = str(S1)
   ...
2. You can check the types of the input and act appropriately:

   if isinstance(S1, basestring):
       # this is a string, strip off the prefix
   elif isinstance(S1, float):
       # this is a float, just use it

Comment: I ended up using the str cast and then stripping them. Thanks!